# Vaadin server push from another thread

Tags: java, vaadin7, server-push

I am using a second thread in my processing, and want to update the progress bar from my second thread. But it's not working for me on it's own. It won't update the progress bar till I manually click a button or do a server event on UI.

```
UI.getCurrent().access(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update the UI as in your code above
                        progressBar_1.setValue(new Float(progress));
                        Notification.show("Preprocessing - 1 Done");                
                    }
                });
```

Comment: have you enabled server push by adding @Push annotation to your UI and adding dependency to vaadin-push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable push in your Vaadin application:

1. Add a dependency to vaadin-push in your project

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
       <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
       <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Define for the servlet that asynchronous communication is supported and add `@com.vaadin.annotations.Push` annotation to the UI:

   ```
   @Push
   public class MyUI extends UI {

       @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
       @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = PushtestUI.class)
       public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
       }

       @Override
       protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
           ..
       }
   }
   ```

More information for example [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Enabling+server+push).

Also, all access to Vaadin components (or for example Containers) from external threads must be locked properly like you already do in your code.

Comment: In which file should I add the dependency?

Comment: Do you use ivy (you have ivy.xml on your project), maven, some other build tool or do you manage manually jar files on your project?